# Azure Blob storage error can't parse a date in spark

Tags: python, azure, apache-spark

I am trying to read a file allocated in azure datalake gen2 into spark dataframe using python.

Code is

```py
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession


# create spark session
key = "some_key"
appName = "DataExtract"
master = "local[*]"
sparkConf = SparkConf() \
    .setAppName(appName) \
    .setMaster(master) \
    .set("fs.azure.account.key.myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net", key)

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).getOrCreate()

data_csv="abfs://test-file-system@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/data.csv"
data_out = "abfs://test-file-system@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/data_out.csv"

# read csv
df = self.spark_session.read.csv(data_csv)

# write csv
df.write.csv(data_out)
```

The file is read and is written well, but I am getting following error

```
ERROR AzureBlobFileSystemStore: Failed to parse the date Thu, 09 Sep 2021 10:12:34 GMT
```

Date seems to be file creation date.
How can I parse the date to avoid getting the error?

Comment: 1. you got a full stack trace you can attach?
2. what version of hadoop-azure is on your classpath, i.e. what is the full name of the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

I tried reproducing the same issue and found it is with these lines that is causing the error.

> ````py
> data_csv="abfs://test-file-system@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/data.csv" data_out =
> "abfs://test-file-system@myaccount.dfs.core.windows.net/data_out.csv"
>
> # read csv df = self.spark_session.read.csv(data_csv) ```
> ````

Here is the code that worked for me when I tried replacing the above lines of code i.e.. `abfs` to `abfss`

```
from pyspark import SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

# create spark session
key = "<Your Storage Account Key>"
appName = "<Synapse App Name>"
master = "local[*]"
sparkConf = SparkConf() \
.setAppName(appName) \
.setMaster(master) \
.set("fs.azure.account.key.<Storage Account Name>.dfs.core.windows.net", key)  

spark = SparkSession.builder.config(conf=sparkConf).getOrCreate()

data_csv="abfss://<ContainerName>@<Storage Account Name>.dfs.core.windows.net/<Directory>"

# read csv
df1 = spark.read.option('header','true')\
.option('delimiter', ',')\
.csv(data_csv + '/sample1.csv')

df1.show()

# write csv
df2 = df1.write.csv(data_csv + '/<Give the name of blob you want to write to>.csv')
```

else you can even try the below code which perfectly worked for me

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import *

account_name = "<StorageAccount Name>"
container_name = "<Storage Account Container Name>"
relative_path = "<Directory path>"
adls_path = 'abfss://%s@%s.dfs.core.windows.net/%s'%(container_name,account_name,relative_path)

dataframe1 = spark.read.option('header','true')\
.option('delimiter', ',')\
.csv(adls_path + '/sample1.csv')

dataframe1.show()

dataframe2 = dataframe1.write.csv(adls_path + '/<Give the name of blob you want to write to>.csv')
```

REFERENCE :
[Synapse Spark – Reading CSV files from Azure Data Lake Storage Gen 2 with Synapse Spark using Python - SQL Stijn (sql-stijn.com)](https://sql-stijn.com/2021/04/20/synapse-spark-reading-a-csv-file/)

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have try to execute the code changing the protocol to abfss as sugested but I'm receiving same error. The strange thing is that it seems to be a property of df after read. I read and then perform df.show() and the error appears again in show() command....

Comment: @vll1990 have you tried with this code?